# How to use tkinter.place()?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to have an entry and I want to have a listbox of fixed size under it which is fixed. and I want to have another listbox of dynamic height. That will appear and disappear in time and also change in size. I want the second listbox (which is actually a dropdown) to be shown over the other listbox which I want it to be fixed. My code for changing the size etc is correct and works perfectly with pack() but then it will move the other listbox up and down as it's size changes. And when I change pack() to place(...) it's not shown at all anymore.

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
entry = Entry(
    root,
    width=50
)
frame = Frame(
    root,
    height=10,
    width=50,
    background="#caeaa9"
)
dropdown = Listbox(
    frame,
    background="#11FF11",
    height=5,
    width=50
)
listbox = Listbox(
    frame,
    background="#FF1111",
    height=10,
    width=50
)
entry.pack()
listbox.pack()
dropdown.place()
frame.pack()
mainloop()
```

But the dropdown does not appear when I run it. What am I missing?

By the way, I want the top border of the dropdown to be exactly on the top border of the listbox and both of them right under the entry.

Comment: Try creating the dropdown widget last.

Comment: I swapped the definition of dropdown and listbox but nth changed @BryanOakley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you don't use the `place` geometry manager. **Ever.** If you want to create larger or more complex interfaces, having to `place` widgets is terrible. I suggest using `grid` instead:

```
import tkinter as tk
# Avoid wildcard imports!

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(
    root,
    width=50
)

frame = tk.Frame(
    root,
    background="#caeaa9"
)

listbox = tk.Listbox(
    frame,
    background="#FF1111",
    height=10,
    width=50
)

dropdown = tk.Listbox(
    frame,
    background="#11FF11",
    height=5,
    width=50
)

entry.pack()
listbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank's. I edited your answer a little so it will work exactly as I want.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. you aren't telling `place` where to place the widget
2. the stacking order (z-index) of the dropdown is behind (lower) than the other listbox, so it will appear under the listbox.

### give explicit coordinates to `place`

I'm not entirely clear where you want the dropdown to appear. Since you say "over" the other listbox, I suggest you use the `in_` parameter to make the coordinates relative to the other listbox, and then use other `place` arguments to place it exactly where you want.

Example:

In the following example I make the dropdown exactly the same width, but half the height of the other listbox.

```
dropdown.place(in_=listbox, x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", relwidth=1.0, relheight=.5)
```

### Fix the stacking order

All widgets have a stacking order. Some people call this a z-index. By default the order is the order in which the widgets are created. Since you create the dropdown before the other listbox, the other listbox has a higher stacking order. That means that it will appear above the dropdown.

A simple solution is to create the dropdown last. If you don't want to do that, you can call the `lift` method of the widget to raise its stacking order. The argument for `lift` is the name of a widget you want to be above.

Example:

```
dropdown.lift(listbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter place is one of the three geometry manager in tkinter. it allows us to specify the position of tkinter widgets in terms of x and y coordinate.
Here is the code example :

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

Button(window,text = "Click Me").place(x = 50,y = 50)

window.mainloop()
```

For more info kindly refer this tutorial on [tkinter place](https://rawpython.com/tkinter-place/)